# IBM mobile first development server unable to start in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, mobilefirst-server

Ibm mobilefirst development server failed to start showing error

```
objc[77281]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
/Users/test/Documents/sathyarajworkspace/eclipse/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_7.1.0.00-20151012-1525/liberty/wlp/bin/server: line 764: 77281 Abort trap: 6           "${JAVA_CMD}" "$@"
```

Since i lost eclipse version of 6.3 i copied eclipse from another mac.
when i tried to run the development server this error shown.
i have also updated to current version of IBM MF still issue exist.

How to fix this issue in mac.

**UPDATE:**

```
killall -9 java
```

Killing java process worked.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port is taken.

Try killing the Java process and then start the server again.

Answer (score 0):

1. in command prompt, run `lsof -i :10080`
2. then kill the ports running with `kill -9 <port_number>`
3. in the "server" tab in eclipse, delete the "mobilefirst development server"
4. close eclipse, reopen eclipse, the server should recreate
5. start the server again